# Python IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, ioerror

I plan to pass a user code script to python logger, run it using python bdb, then log the output in a file.

Here is my code in python logger:

```
  try:
    logger._runscript(script_str)
  except bdb.BdbQuit:
    pass
  finally:
    logger.finalize(filename)
```

where logger.finalize is defined below as function finalizer(output, filename).

The bdb will spawn a new thread and call the following finalizer function after execution:

```
def finalizer(output, filename): 
  outfile = open(filename , 'a')
  outfile.write(json.dumps(output, indent = 4))
  outfile.close()
```

Here output is execution result and we will write it to a file with filename.

I tested the three lines in the finalizer function, and they ran okay.

However, when they were called from python logger, I always get the following error message:

```
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: filename
```

I only open one file, append a string to its end, then close it. Why are there "too many open files"? Can anyone kindly point me to the problem?

Here is the TraceBack info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./exec.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "./exec.py", line 82, in main
  File "./exec.py", line 45, in run
  File "path to project/logger.py", line 1321, in exec_script_str
  File "path to project/logger.py", line 1292, in finalize
  File "./exec.py", line 24, in finalizer
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'test01.py'
```

Comment: Can you show the whole traceback?

Comment: TraceBack info added, line 24 in exec.py points to outfile = open(filename , 'a'). I suspect the problem is pdb thread can not open/close file properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to check the other places your program opens files. This may not be the source of the leak.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've double checked the code. Finalizer is the only function that opens a file, and with each open immediately follows a close. I still have no idea ...

Comment: What about `script_str`? Is that a Python script? Does it open any files?

Comment: script_str is just very simple Python script like "x=1\nprint x\n" etc. I moved the file operations out of finalizer itself, instead, finalizer simply returns output. Same thing for the finally statement in logger. Then I open/write the returned output to files. IOErrors are gone!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like the logger from the standard library. Rather it looks like you are trying to use a third-party [library](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/blob/master/v3/docs/developer-overview.md) that provides a sandbox environment. One of the restrictions is which that it forbids file access (see [line 1233](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/blob/master/v3/pg_logger.py)).

If you are creating the logger object yourself you can disable these security checks by creating with the appropriate flag eg.

```
def exec_str_with_user_ns(script_str, user_ns, finalizer_func):
    logger = PGLogger(False, False, False, finalizer_func, disable_security_checks=True)

    try:
        logger._runscript(script_str, user_ns)
    except bdb.BdbQuit:
        pass
    finally:
        return logger.finalize()
```